# Not Working function get data using jQuery call. Help me please

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
             function getDept() {
                var deplist;
                //Get Department
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@(Url.Action("getDeptFK", "Settings"))',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) {
                        deplist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
                return deplist;
            }
```

function return undefined but debug value in **success**  work !

Comment: I hope you realize that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` is quit unnecessary. It's as useful as  `x - 5 + 5`. Just use `data` directly. There is no reason to convert the object/array to JSON first and then parse the JSON back to an object/array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous so you can't return anything from it.

One way is to rewrite your `getDept()` function to this:

```
function getDept() {
    var deplist;
    //Get Department

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@(Url.Action("getDeptFK", "Settings"))',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            deplist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
     });
}
```

then you can pass it to a variable:

```
var result = getDept();
```

and get the data that is returned by the AJAX call like this:

```
result.success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Aren't `JSONP` calls ***synchronous*** by default?

Comment: My mistake: `Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation`